# Get date of a candle

Tags: pine-script-v5

Im trying to get the date of the last candle, but at the moment i get only the current date.

What im looking for is this data:

```
Year => 2022
Month => December
Day => 24
```

At this moment i get this values using:

```
year(timenow)
month(timenow)
dayofmonth(timenow)
```

But what's i would like is getting this value based on last daily candle.
If i use Bareplay, using timenow, the value dont change.

Any suggestion?
Merry Christmas at all ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **time** function :

*The time function returns the UNIX time of the current bar for the specified timeframe and session or NaN if the time point is out of session.*
see : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_time

time(timeframe.period) will return you the time of the actual bar, not the time now.
Then you can use year( ) , month( ) and dayofthemonth( ) to retrieve your values.

Comment: Thanks you so much G.Lebret. yours solution It works perfectly and i've found where i was the pseudo-error. Thank you again